# Push notification permission request not asking from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

For my ASP.NET (MVC) web application, I have used push notifications for the first time. I have no previous experience with SignalR and Push Notifications. So I have followed some tutorials and added that feature to my project.

The thing is when I debug and run the application on my computer in Visual Studio, in the address bar it shows the popup message for requesting permission for the push notification.

But When I publish this project to my local server (IIS) and accessed it through the assigned Local IP and the port, It wasn't asking permission for the popup.

Can I know why is the reason that happens and how to avoid this?

Here are some screenshots,

This is on my PC when debug and run the project.

[image]

This is on the Local IIS Server
[image]

Comment: You need to serve the website from a `https://` origin, not `http://192.168.2...`.